# Is there any way to create a blank solution (.sln) file first in Visual Studio 2017 and then add projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

As we know we have `Other Project Types` template in other versions of Visual Studio but not available in 2017.

How can we add empty solution file in VS 2017?

[image]

Comment: There's no point in having a blank solution file though.

Comment: @DavidG So, we can't add emplty solution in VS 2017?

Comment: I still have a "Other Project Types" node in my VS2017, leading to a blank solution. So it's not a blanket "it's not there in 2017"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever my vs don't have this template. How can i add this? Had there any installation error that's why i don't have it?

Comment: What version of VS are you using? This should actually be there by default

Comment: @Freggar  VS 2017 enterprise

Comment: It should be there by default, try by doing repair VS may be

Comment: @DavidG - it is extremely useful, for taking control over your folder structure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your valuable comments and answers. I got the `Other Project Types` template when i have installed [this vsix](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) .[image]

Thanks...

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have it before you installed anything?  And just closed the current Solution first?

Comment: I haven't this before

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is. Just go to Other Project Types -> Visual Studio Solutions.

Visual Studio Community 2017
Version: `15.7.2`

[image]

Comment: The OP has indicated that it isn't there in VS2017. Whilst we both clearly disagree with their assessment, their screenshot clearly doesn't have the "Other Project Types" node where we would expect to see it.

Comment: whops I honestly didn't notice that. Hmmm. interesting

Comment: He does not have the C++ workload installed.  The blank.sln template in Common7/IDE/SolutionTemplate directory definitely smells like one that requires it, .vsdir is a strong hint.

Comment: @HansPassant And neither do I. This just seems like a broken VS installation

Answer (score 4):

Your screenshot is for ***Add*** new project (see the top left caption), meaning you already have a Solution open.

Close it first. Then use **New Project** and look under Other Project Types.